# In google colab when i read 1.5 gb csv file it occupy 6 gb RAM. I have checked using psutil.virtual_memory().available. What is the reason?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, memory, google-colaboratory

`psutil.virtual_memory().available`:

> 24.50384521484375

```
test =pd.read_csv("test_csv.csv")
psutil.virtual_memory().available
```

> 18.723899841308594

Comment: Call `df.memory_usage()` to see how much memory your individual columns are taking up and see why that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the internal python representation of the data takes more memory than the bare file size.

For example, on my particular version of python, a non-empty string object takes up a minimum of 38 bytes:

```
>>> x = '1'
>>> sys.getsizeof(x)
38
```

So if you had a file that just contained the number 1, the file itself would only be one byte.  But when you read the file contents into a python variable, it takes up a lot more memory than that.

Comment: That 38 number will be different on different Python versions and builds - it looks like you're probably on a 32-bit build. (Also, you tested a nonempty string. An empty string can be smaller, though the actual effect on memory consumption is likely to be nonexistent due to internal fragmentation.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Edited to make it clear that my example does not speak for all versions of Python.